# Ember.js collection itemIdBinding

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to output a collection and give each item a unique id of my own choosing. I know I can give it a class with a binding but how about and id?

What I want to do is something like:

```
{{collection contentBinding="MyApp.myController" tagName="ul" itemIdBinding="content.id"}}
```

where id is a computed property on my model. If I do itemClassBinding it works as I'd expect an I can give each item a fixed id with itemId= but is there no way to give each item an id based on a property of the model?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not the right way to do this in the collection view. You should bind the id on the actual view.

```
{{#collection contentBinding="MyApp.myController" tagName="ul"}}
      {{MyApp.myView idBinding="content.myID"}}
{{/collection}}
```